# Is it possible to move boot process into SSD part (nvme) of SSHD?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, ssd

I installed ubuntu 20.04 as dual boot on my default windows 10 machine (ASUS ROG G531GD). I didn't realize disk I have on the machine is SSHD (Solid State Hybrid Drive) which has a part of SSD, a part of HDD and not full SSD.

Booting Ubuntu 20.04 takes quite long. I think I installed it on the HDD part, I shrunk my D drive, then free it up to be installed ubuntu. Windows is in C drive. So is there a way to move the booting process from the HDD part into the SSD part of my SSHD? So that I can experience fast boot as I have on my Windows?

Comment: Look at `systemd-analyze blame` after reading `man systemd-analyze`. Also read `man hier`, the Filesystem Hieracy doc, and tells you which directory is which. Also. "C drive", "D drive" are Windows constructs and not used in Linux. Linux uses partitions.

Comment: And no, the SSD part is for cache only, a gimmick for the most part. It's just a HDD like any other but feels a little faster.